# Bootstrap TypeAhead with MySQL not working

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, twitter-bootstrap, typeahead

I have the following in my html:

```
    <td>
        Maintenance Provider
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type=text name='maintenance' id='maintenance'/>
    </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I have the following in the JS, which uses Bootstrap typeahead:

```
$(function() {  
    $('#maintenance').typeahead({ 
        source: function (query, process) {
            return $.getJSON(
                '/processing.php?search_preencoded=Y',
                { query: query },
                function (data) {
                    return process(data);
                }
            );
        }
    });
});
```

And the processing.php code snippet is:

```
if(isset($_GET['search_preencoded'])){
    $db2=new mysqli("localhost","root","","external");
    $sql="select * from preencoded where content like '".$_POST['query']."%%'";
    $rs=$db2->query($sql);
    $nm=$rs->num_rows;
    for($i=0;$i<$nm;$i++){
        $row=$rs->fetch_assoc();

        $data[]=$row['content'];

    }
    echo json_encode($data);
}
```

But when I type the content that's supposedly in the database, the typeahead doesn't work!  Note that the table has only two fields: code and content.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: any console errors???

Comment: i think you have not referenced typeahead.js in your page ... download it from here  https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js

Comment: but the typeahead works.  if i place an array on source: instead of the function, it works fine

Comment: there are no console errors.  nothing happens when i type something in the text field.

Answer (score 1):

I think your **LIKE** is wrong try:

```
    $sql = "select * from preencoded where content like '%" . $_POST['query'] . "%'";
```

Take a look at - http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-like-clause.htm

Depending on what type of search you want you will need a % before, after or before and after the $_POST['query'].

Also format your question so it is easier to read.